# Priming for smudge coverup

Tags: painting

I have some deep toned stain smudge over semigloss white. Should I just

1. paint white semigloss over it, or
2. Prime regular white primer, then paint, or
3. Prime gray primer, then paint?

Or something fourth?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you  can't clean the smudges off I would seal the stain. I would use Bin or Kilz or other similar product. They are a shellac like product that seals the stain. This is important to keep the stain from bleeding through the new paint. After the sealer has cured you can prime and paint.